# Promise nesting vs chaining style

Tags: javascript, scope, promise

New to promises; consider the case where there is `promiseA()` and `promiseB(a)` which depends on the first result, and I want to collect results from both and perform a third action `doSomething(a, b)`:

**Style A (closure/nesting)**

```
promiseA().then(function (resultA) {
  return (promiseB(resultA).then(function (resultB) {
    doSomething(resultA, resultB);
  }));
});
```

**Style B (return value/chaining)**

```
promiseA().then(function (resultA) {
  return Promise.all([resultA, promiseB(resultA)]);
}).spread(function (resultA, resultB) {
  doSomething(resultA, resultB);
});
```

As far as I can tell, these are equivalent:

- Same sequencing constraint between `promiseA` and `promiseB`
- Final promise returns `undefined`
- Final promise is rejected if `promiseA` or `promiseB` are rejected, or `doSomething` throws.

As a matter of style, Style B reduces indentation (pyramid of doom).

However, Style B is more difficult to refactor. If I need to introduce an intermediate `promiseA2(a)` and `doSomething(a, a2, b)`, I need to modify 3 lines (`Promise.all`, `spread`, `doSomething`), which can lead to mistakes (accidental swapping etc), while with Style A I only to modify 1 line (`doSomething`) and the variable name makes it clear which result it is. In large projects, this may be significant.

Are there other non-functional trade-offs between the two styles? More/less memory allocation in one vs the other? More/fewer turns around the event loop? Better/worse stack traces on exceptions?

Comment: `const resultA = await promiseA();
const resultB = await promiseB(resultA);
doSomething(resultA, resultB);`

Comment: See also [How do I access previous promise results in a `.then()` chain?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/1048572) for an overview of different approaches

Answer (score 1):

I think the non-functional trade-offs between the two methods are not so important: the second method has some overhead in creating the array, and spreading the corresponding results, and it will create one more promise. However in an asynchronous flow, all this is negligible in my opinion.

Your major concern seems to be the ease of refactoring.

For that I would suggest to use an array of functions, and `reduce` over it:

```js
[promiseA, promiseB, doSomething].reduce( (prom, f) =>
    prom.then( (res = []) => ( f(...res) || prom).then( [].concat.bind(res) ) )
, Promise.resolve() );


// Sample functions
function wait(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

function promiseA() {
    console.log('promiseA()');
    return wait(500).then(_ => 13);
}

function promiseB(a) {
    console.log('promiseB(' + a + ')');
    return wait(500).then(_ => a + 2);
}

function doSomething(a, b) {
    console.log('doSomething(' + a + ',' + b + ')');
}
```

The idea is that the next function in the `then` callback chain gets all of the previous results passed as arguments. So if you want to inject a promise-returning function in the chain, it is a matter of inserting it in the array. Still, you would need to pay attention to the arguments that are passed along: they are cumulative in this solution, so that `doSomething` is not an exception to the rule.

If on the other hand, you only want `doSomething` to get all results, and only pass the most recent result to each of the intermediate functions, then the code would look like this:

```js
[promiseA, promiseB].reduce( (prom, f) =>
    prom.then( (res = []) => f(...res.slice(-1)).then( [].concat.bind(res) ) )
, Promise.resolve() ).then(res => doSomething(...res));

function wait(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

function promiseA() {
    console.log('promiseA()');
    return wait(100).then(_ => 13);
}

function promiseB(a) {
    console.log('promiseB(' + a + ')');
    return wait(100).then(_ => a + 2);
}

function doSomething(a, b) {
    console.log('doSomething(' + a + ',' + b + ')');
}
```